# Pacman wants to install an old version

Tags: package-management, pacman, arch-arm

I have an arch linux and want to install lsof using pacman. But I get an error that the lsof-package is not available:

```
#pacman -S lsof         
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (1) lsof-4.89-1

Total Download Size:   0.09 MiB
Total Installed Size:  0.22 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] y
:: Retrieving packages ...
error: failed retrieving file 'lsof-4.89-1-armv7h.pkg.tar.xz' from  mirror.archlinuxarm.org : The requested URL returned error: 404
warning: failed to retrieve some files
error: failed to commit transaction (unexpected error)
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
```

Pacman expects a version 4.89 but on the server there is a version 4.90
(http://de.mirror.archlinuxarm.org/armv7h/extra/lsof-4.90-1-armv7h.pkg.tar.xz)

So appearently the version info pacman is using is outdated. How can I tell pacman what exact version is available?

Kind regards
Florian

Comment: `pacman -Syu lsof`...

Comment: I don't know how Arch does things, but is the above an Answer?

Comment: Yes it is. @jasonwryan, please post that as an answer, not as a comment :-)

Answer (score 1):

[404 errors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) are exactly what they say they are, the server can not find the requested resource.

This error *always* occurs because you have not updated your local database, so pacman is requesting a version that has already been superseded on the mirror.

This is why you should always ensure that your local database is in sync (`-y`) when you update (`u`): `pacman -Syu lsof` will solve your "problem".

Better still, just `pacman -Syu` regularly to keep your system and local database up-to-date; the only supported way to manage a rolling release distribution.

Comment: On a side note and completely unrelated to this one: is there a `systemctl` timer (or something similar) that runs that command or just the `checkupdates` script in order to automatically know if there are updates?

Comment: @ɐuıɥɔɐɯ You would'nt run `-Syu` from a timer. That is what `checkupdates` is for; and, yes, I run it on a timer every hour.